# Cómo usar tracking.js IONIC

Tags: ionic, typescript, opencv

Tengo un poco de experiencia con IONIC, tengo un requerimiento para poder detectar un rostro usando la cámara pero no he podido hacerlo, siempre he detectado rostros usando C++ o Python con OPENCV pero en IONIC estoy "pataleando".

He tratado de hacerlo usando tracking.js ya lo tengo en mi proyecto pero nose como hacerlo para que funcione o detecte rostros a traves de la cámara, es decir, nose como desde el .html hacer que detecte abriendo la camara.

He revisado este ejemplo:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41398500/importing-trackingjs-as-third-party-library-in-ionic2

Pero es con imagenes mi requerimiento es a traves de la camara (vivo)

Hay alguna forma de hacerlo a través de esta librería o otra?